# Video Creation Adobe Flash/Flex

Tags: flash, apache-flex

I am looking for a way to create a video that will take some provided data like name, age, etc and generate a video file like mp4/flv/etc from Adobe Flash/Flex in a programmatic manner.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Do it on the server and live stream the results.

Comment: @drkstr1 Thanks. Yes that is the idea but I wanted to convert it into mp4. is this can be done so that i can stream based on the user device.

Comment: ffmpeg has the ability to trans-code and stream on the fly. I believe Flash Media Server should also be able to handle this, if you are looking for a commercial solution. https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg has the ability to trans-code and stream on the fly. You could then pipe this through some kind of media server (such as FMS) and use the built in functionality to modify the stream to your liking.

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/adobe-media-server/articles/metadata_video_streaming.html